# Getting max date of values based on another column

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-statements, max, google-sheets-formula

The problem I am trying to solve is I need to fill in column `'F'` with each value's respective max date, or latest date.
Here is a screenshot of what it should look like:
[image]

The solution is to the right of it. I did it manually for demo purposes but I need to do it for a much larger dataset, and need a more efficient way of doing it.
Can you please help me with the proper formula here?

Answer (score 0):

if latest is based on the row use:

```
=SORTN(SORT({B2:B, A2:A}, ROW(A2:A), 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]

if latest is based on the date use:

```
=SORTN(SORT({B2:B, A2:A}, A2:A, 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)
```

[image]